# Navigation Bar Hidden

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm having issues with my navigation bar. It isn't showing up where it should, and under "Simulated Metrics" in the Xcode interface builder the "Top Bar" property is set to "Black Navigation Bar". In my code, I also have the hidden property set to false, so that shouldn't be of issue.

I do have a `UITabBar` at the bottom, however, that is also accounted for in the "Simulated Metrics" category.

See: http://postimage.org/image/jv4lremwl/full/

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code/context from where you're showing your view.

Answer (score 2):

The "Simulated Metrics is as it's name indicates: a "simulated representation" that is not connected with any Object that you will have created (or not) in your code (or in the XCode interface builder). If you set the simulated `NavigationBar` to black or whatever color in the simulated metrics, that means nothing to your actual project because it is only a visual reference of how it will be displayed if you actually implement it.

If you want to have a "real" navigation top bar you have to implement a `UINavigationController`, or add manually a `UINavigationBar` (through code or visually).

Comment: Okay, so I have a navigation bar I placed in there on my own, however, the view won't pop.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to integrate Tab bar Contrller and Navigation bar controller is by creating them with code. ( That is what i use mostly )

```
//Creating the navigation bar
//rVC is some root view controller you have on your code

UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [nav1 pushViewController:rVC animated:YES];
    nav1.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[rVC release];

//Creating the tab bar custom image and title
UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nav1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav1Image.png"] tag:1];
    [nav1 setTabBarItem:tab1];

//making the navigation bar visible in the inside tab bar
UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1, nil];
```

Hope it is helpful for you.
Cheers